# LoginButton asking for friends list permission, why?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am using the built in LoginButton widget in the facebook sdk, I haven't made any changes to it I just include it in my xml layout file and call `setSessionStatusCallback` nothing else.

However, when I click the login button facebook says I am asking for both basic info AND the friends list.  I do not want permission to view the users friends, and after looking though the source of LoginButton it seems like it shouldn't be asking either, its `permissions` String list is empty.

Whats going on here?

update: adding my code by request.

```
    final LoginButton facebook = (LoginButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
    if(facebook != null){
            if(Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getActivity()) != null){
                facebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                facebook.setSessionStatusCallback(new StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if(session.isOpened()){
                            showProgress(true);
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    Log.d("test", user.getId());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: I know you said you don't have anything in the permissions option, but could you post up your code so we can get a better idea of whats going on?

Comment: @steve I updated my question and added the code as you requested.

Comment: Strange. I wonder do you have any default permissions associated in the developer toolbar? The session object can request default permissions if none are stated.  Thats the only thing I could think of. Sorr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking for basic info + friends list is the *most basic* permissions that an app can request.  If you do not supply any additional read permissions, then those two permissions are the only ones that will show up, and I do not believe you can remove them.

I believe we do this because when integrating your app with Facebook, the inherent reason is to make your app social and to provide a distribution channel for your app.  So the friends list permission is added by default because you should use that permission to encourage the user to share your app with their friends if they wish to do so with the app requests dialog etc.

Comment: Yes well, I'm just implementing a SSO so it seems fishy when I ask for a friends list, the iOS counterpart does not ask for a friends list.

Comment: It's probably the new login dialog that came with the new FB4A + Android SDK that the iOS counterpart doesn't have yet.  I just authed an app on iOS with the old iOS SDK and you're correct in that it didn't explicitly say friends, but if you go to your app settings on Facebook, it says that they have access to your list of friends.

Comment: Ok thanks, I hope you change this in the future, its nice you want to promote social apps, but not really the spirit of SSO.

Comment: Same issue here. One of my apps uses Facebook login (Android and iOS), which requires an access token which is used in server side to fetch email address. However it seems fishy when it asks for "Friends List" permission. We are using OAuth 2.0. Google+ login works fine.